# specify return value based on ajax post data recieved

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to validate my form based on the returned data value, only, It wont return false unless I return the whole post function false. is it possible to differentiate how it is returned based on which condition is met? this is what I have :

```
function postValidation(){

   $.post('file.php',$('#form').serialize(), function(data) {

      if(data !== 'good') {
             alert(data);
             return false;
          }  else

            if(data  == 'good') 
            {return true;}
   });

}
```

Comment: You cannot return the result of an asynchronous task (**A** jax) from a synchronous function.

Comment: It's asynchronous, so the function returns before the results are received, and the return statement is in a different function scope.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Return data after ajax call success](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is not possible as such.  You can't use the return value from an ajax callback.  Everything has to be done within the callback itself (or any dependent callbacks).

```
$("#form").on('submit', function (e) {
    //stop form from submitting
    postValidation();
    e.preventDefault();
});

function postValidation () {
   $.post(...).done(function (data) {
       if (data === 'good') {
           //handle form success; do whatever you want
           window.location.reload();
       }
   });
}
```